# Power View: Dynamic Filters possible?

Tags: excel, reporting-services, business-intelligence, powerview

My Boss wants to Switch to Power View from Reporting Services, but he wants to know if everything you could do in SSRS is available in Power View first.

One of the things I noticed immediately is that I couldn't define the filter values for the months dynamically (is this really true?)

What I want is something in the form I used in SSRS parameters as default value:

```
cstr(year(dateadd("m", 0, now()))) + "-"+ right( "0"+ cstr(month(dateadd("m", 0, now()))), 2)
```

for the current year-month

Is any there way to do this in Power View?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to filter the whole view or an element to only display data form the current month dynamically?

I do this by adding a column to the data set "FilterYearMonth" for example.

Set the column =IF(YEAR([Date Column])&MONTH([Date Column]) = YEAR(NOW())&MONTH(NOW()), 1, 0)

Then filter the whole view or element to only display when "FilterYearMonth" = 1

Comment: I guess that's all that's left to do,
thanks for your Great Help.
And just for the People out there, here the Correct Syntax for the Filter: =IF(YEAR([Date Column])&MONTH([Date Column]) = YEAR(NOW())&MONTH(NOW()); 1; 0)